# App crashes even before launch. How can I debug this?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, crash

I have an app and some users have reported that their app is being crashed on the launch. But I see no crash reports, not on Crashlytics, not on Xcode. Probably because the app crashes even before applicationDidFinishLaunching is called.

You can find the [video recording here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvfkBF3PGjk) I got from the user.
iOS version: 14.2.1

How can I debug this? What can be the issue? Any idea can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if your app has small amount of code I would just start a new one and copy step by step the content of your old app in your new app and keep going until the problems comes. This way you could figure out the origin.

Comment: How is distributed your App? Through XCode? Through TestFlight (doesn't seem so, since there is not the yellow dot)? When did you deploy it? It might not be valid anymore. XCode ad-hoc deployed app might have a week of life expectancy...

Comment: You can ask users for their logs.

Comment: The problem is solved. It's nothing related to the app. Apparently, there is an error with some devices on iOS 14.2. AdServices framework is causing the crash even if you don't import it. You can find the solution here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/673708

Answer (score 1):

In order to see a crash report in the analytics system like Crashlytics or Sentry, your users need to restart the app after crash and keep it opened at least for ~20 seconds. Crash reports are being sent to analytics systems as batches of data once per some period of time and never right at the moment of a crash. That's why you won't see that crash reports there - they will never be sent.

As for the possible reasons, here are a few ideas if you can't reproduce it yourself on your device:

1. If the users who experience crashes have just **updated** your app to a higher version *and* if you use CoreData or Realm and have recently upgraded your schema, a crash on launch could happen due to the absence or incorrectness of database migrations.
2. Alternatively, a crash could happen if your code tries to access some hardware features, unavailable on certain Apple devices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is solved. It's nothing related to the app. Apparently, there is an error with some devices on iOS 14.2. AdServices framework is causing the crash even if you don't import it. You can find the solution here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/673708